# Definition(s) of polarization of waves

Tags: optics, waves, electromagnetic-radiation, definition, polarization

Is there more than one definition to "polarization" in the context of waves?

In some cases, I've seen the term "direction of polarization", which I presume it refers to the direction of oscillation.
In other context, I see this word use as a process of turning unpolarized waves into polarized waves.
Also, there are times whereby people say that "polarization only occurs in transverse waves", which implies that polarization is a property/phenomenon of transverse wave.

So is polarization a property, a process, an adjective to describe the direction of oscillation, or is it all of the above? Is there any other definition of polarization I'm missing here in the context of waves?

Comment: Yes, it is an overloaded term that can mean those things you have listed, in various contexts, and a bit more.

Comment: Oh.... What other possible meanings could the word take on?

Comment: Electric polarisation of dielectric materials. Totally different thing that has nothing whatsoever to do with waves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Polarisation is the **process** by which unpolarised light is converted into polarised light. This can be done by passing the light through an instrument known as a polariser. When we say "polarisation only occurs in transverse waves", we mean that only transverse waves such as light can be polarised whereas longitudinal waves such as sound cannot be polarised. Check (https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/323515/364859).

Although it may sound awkward to say that the "Polarisation of light is a property shown by transverse waves", it simply means that light can undergo polarisation.

This is a good definition of polarisation:

Polarisation is the process by which unpolarised light is converted to polarised light (in which light’s electric field begins to vibrate in a single plane) after passing through a polariser.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I still have a fairly minor question. Am I right to say that transverse waves such as gravitational waves and P-waves can also be polarised? If so, then these waves – too – do not comprise of oscillating electric & magnetic vector fields (much like the explanation you gave for longitudinal waves). So is there a different reason behind why longitudinal waves do not exhibit polarisation?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: @Tham thanks for pointing it out. I edited it accordingly. Check the similar question posted earlier. Hope this helps.

Answer (score -1):

A wave is polarised if a direction perpendicular to the direction of propagation exists. Since water waves (from a stone in a pond) always oscillate perpendicular to the horizon, they are always polarised.

For long-wave radio waves, the plane of polarisation is always given for the electrical component of the EM radiation. This is aligned perpendicular to the earth's surface for standing antennae (rods) or horizontally for tensioned antenna wires.

A polarisation is also given for circular radio waves. Spiral antennas can be designed to be left-turning or right-turning.

As already noted in the comments, the term polarisation is also used for the state of separated charge carriers.

It is also used for the magnetic rotation of electrons, as occurs in magnets or magnetised materials. And last but not least, in spintronics, the common alignment of the spin of electrons is produced, which is also polarisation.

And the fact that the process of generation is also called polarisation is perfectly OK, isn't it? By the way, just as the device for this is often called a polariser.