Polarisation and dispersion relation for electromagnetic waves with complex $k$
I'm attempting to answer this past exam question:

The monochromatic plane wave solution for the electric field is given as:
$$
\begin{equation*}
\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}, t)=\mathbf{E} \exp [i(\mathbf{k} \cdot \mathbf{r}-\omega t]) \tag{14}
\end{equation*}
$$
When developing an intuition to the plane wave as the solution to electromagnetic wave equations, we have generally considered scenarios in which the wave vector $\mathbf{k}$ has been real. However, many physical systems are actually described by a complex $\mathbf{k}$.

(a) (3 points) Consider a monochromatic plane wave with an electric field pointing in the $\hat{\mathbf{x}}$ direction with magnitude $E_{0}$. Let the wave vector $\mathbf{k}=h \hat{\mathbf{z}}+i \kappa \hat{\mathbf{y}}$ where $\kappa$ and $h$ are both real parameters. Write down a simplified expression for the electric field $\mathbf{E}(\mathbf{r}, t)$ 
(b) (5 points) Using the wave equation for $\mathbf{E}$, find a relationship between $\kappa, h$, and $\omega$. This is the dispersion relation for this wave. 
(c) (5 points) Write down an expression for the magnetic field $\mathbf{B}$ using Faraday's law. For a plane wave with real $\mathbf{k}$, the magnetic field is transverse to the direction of propagation. Is this still the case?
(d) (5 points) Using the results in part (b), in what cases would the polarisation of the magnetic field B be approximately circular?

I've got a dispersion relation by substituting $\bf{E}$ into the wave equation, and the relation I've got is that $\omega = c\sqrt{h^2-\kappa^2}$.
The problem with $\omega = c\sqrt{h^2-\kappa^2}$ is that since the polarization of the $\bf{B}$ field is $\hat{\bf{n}} = ih\hat{\bf{y}} + \kappa \hat{\bf{z}}$, we need $\kappa = h$ for circular polarisation, and then $\omega = 0$. Is this possible? Or is my dispersion relation wrong?

Please do not post images of texts you want to quote, but type it out instead so it is readable for all users and so that it can be indexed by search engines. For formulae, use MathJax instead. Another helpful tip: there's no point mentioning that "ChatGPT didn't help", if it did you wouldn't need to ask here right? And you're not going to get advice on how to get better results from ChatGPT on this site because this isn't the purpose of this site. So better avoid the mention of it altogether :)

Cheers, thanks for the advice; all fixed up.

$\kappa=h$ might give circular polarisation for a wave travelling along the x-axis. But it isn't.

Yes, but the $\bf{B}$ field isn't transverse; it's equation is given by $\vec{B} = -E_0 e^{-\kappa y} h \cos(hz-\omega t) \hat{y} + -E_0 e^{-\kappa y} h \sin(hz-\omega t) \hat{z}$, which means even though it's travelling in the $\hat{z}$ direction, its polarisation has a component in the $\hat{z}$. @ProfRob

@Deeb the definition of circular polarisation requires transverse, out of phase components. Also, IMO, "polarisation" refers to the E field direction, I have never heard of it being applied to the E-field and B-field separately. (I also don't quite agree with your B-field equation). Circular polarisation applies only to transverse waves. e.g. https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/323509/why-cant-longitudinal-waves-be-polarised

@ProfRob I see. There's probably something wrong with my B field. I've looked and im unsure what my mistake is. And you're right about the fact that circular polarisation is only for transverse waves; but I used Faraday's Law to find the B field from the E field and it isn't coming out as transverse.

I agree. But I disagree on the exact direction you have for B and there should also be a denominator of $\omega$ somewhere.
